# Suppose $f(x)$ is a total computable function. Use minimlization to show that there is a computable function $g(y)$

Tags: computability

Suppose $f(x)$ is a total computable function. Use minimalization to show that there is a computable function $g(y)$ with $dom$ $g = im$ $f$ and $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y \in dom$ $g$

I know this then means that $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y \in im$ $f$ but I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Haha it autocorrected me :P I meant minimalization but i've also heard it called minimisation

Comment: *Minimization* (US) or *minimisation* (UK) is the usual term. (But I really liked *mineralization*: autocorrection sometimes produces really funny results.)

Answer (score 1):

$g(y)=\min\{x:f(x)=y\}$ (plus a few more characters because the site doesn't like minimalization of answers)

Comment: I have no idea how you got to this answer, can you explain?

Comment: I'm assuming $g(y)$ is the minimum $x$ such that $f(x)=y$ but I don't get how

Comment: The question was not to prove something about some already given $g$, which might very well not have chosen the minimum $x$ for each $y$, but to show that there exists a computable $g$ satisfying the requirements in the question. So, of the (possibly many) $g$'s that satisfy $f(g(y))=y$ for all $y\in\text{Im}(f)$, I chose the simplest one. It has the advantage that minimization immediately proves that this $g$ is computable.